# Loop for formatting rows in increments

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where I would like to format every 11th through 13th row like the 5th through 7th row. I got this far then realized I do not know how to advance the loop. So obviously the sub is a feeble attempt at only formatting rows 11-13 37× if I even did that correctly.

```
Rows("5:7").Select
Selection.Copy
For i = 1 To 37
    Rows("11:13").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i
```

Comment: `Next` "advances the loop". It is really unclear what you are asking about here. Could you try clarifying your question a bit?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you wish to start with copying the formats in rows 5:7 then advance by 11 rows to rows 16:18, 27:29, 38:40, etc for a total of 3 additional groups and paste the formats. To do this, you need to introduce the **Step** parameter into your [For Next statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The Step parameter is always there but it is defaulted to *1* so it generally isn't shown unless you want to advance by a different increment than *1*.

```
For i = 0 To 33 step 11
    if i = 0 then
        Rows("5:7").copy
    else
        Rows("5:7").offset(i,0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, _
                      Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    end if
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The `Step 11` means that *i* will increment by *11* for each cycle. This is used in the `.Offset(i, 0)` to advance further down the worksheet.

Comment: Hey looks like it works. I just had to adjust 33 to the full number or rows in the sheet and adjust the step to 4. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @VBAtion - Glad to hear that got you sorted out. I will admit that I had a hard time following the math behind the increments and number of loops from your question but perhaps my mistake got you to a better understanding of the processes involved. Good luck with your project!

Comment: yes probably better if I didn't include code at all as I am so new.

Comment: @VBAtion - No, you're doing it right. The people reviewing your question to see if they can provide a solution **want** to see what you have tried thus far, even if it won't compile let alone run as expected. I got more information from your code snippet than I did from your narrative and I was only able to suggest what I did reply with using a combination of the two. Please do not abandon posting code you have tried so far!